# How to retrieve image names from a folder in Asp.net VB.

Tags: asp.net, image, telerik

I am using telerik editor for uploading images which are getting stored in images folder.
Now I want to fetch all images and paths from that image folder and save only image name and path in to separate database table.

Can I do this in asp.net VB ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path")
```

method returns files for passed path parameter...

In asp.net application you can use Server.MapPath method which will return physical path for virtual directory.